# Which concrete type can I use to instantiate a variable of type ICollection<T>

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, collections

I have a class:

```
public class A {
        public int Id { set; get; }
        public virtual ICollection<B> Bs { set; get; }
}
```

I want to add a constructor to class `A` which instantiates the property of type ICollection. What type can I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To instantiate ICollection...

```
public class A {
    public A() 
    {
        this.Bs = new Collection<B>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<B> Bs { get; set; }
}
```

Here's a quick introduction to interfaces which you may find helpful...

`ICollection` is an `Interface`, which means that it is a `Contract` for a `Class`.

For example if I say that a `Car` must have a number of `Seats`, I will create an `Interface` called `ICar`, and a property on it called `Seats`.

```
public interface ICar {
    int Seats { get; set; }
}
```

Since this is just an `Interface` we can not instantiate it directly, we need a `Class` to implement this contract.

```
public class Car : ICar {
    public int Seats {get; set; }
}
```

Now we can instantiate `ICar car = new Car();` because the `Class Car` implemented the `ICar` interface. This is no different than what's going on internally with the `Collection` class and `List` class, they both implement ICollection.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion. I would like to know should I use `new Collection<B>();` or `new List<B>` I don't know which Entity Framework uses.

Comment: It doesn't matter, you can use either one because they both implement ICollection.

Comment: Ive updated my answer to provide more in depth explanation, if you've found this answer helpful please mark it as the chosen answer, thanks.